# Flash messages passport-local-mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport-local

I am having trouble trying to find out where to get the flash messages

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', { 
        user : req.user,
        failureMessage : req.flash('fail')
    });
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect : '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect : '/login',
    failureFlash : true,
}), function(req, res) {
    // none of this will run right?
});
```

I'm rendering a login page and when the user submits data, it goes to the passport.authenticate middleware and it takes care of the rest without going to the additional callback so how can I get the flash message so I can show it when redirecting back to the /login page?

Another issue is whether I am supposed to do

```
passport.use(User.createStrategy());
```

or

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
```

The docs tell me to use the first one: https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose#simplified-passportpassport-local-configuration but I have yet to see a tutorial use the first one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out how to work the flash messages. Seems like this should do it.

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', { 
        user : req.user,
        error : req.flash('error')
    });
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect : '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect : '/login',
    failureFlash : { type: 'error', message: 'Invalid username or password.' }
}));
```

Comment: I know I'm coming here after 3 years and 8 months, but you absolute legend. I've been trying to look for a solution to Flash messages to work with passport-local-mongoose for 2 straight days, until I finally came across your solution. Kudos for finding the solution yourself in the end. I can't believe there's still only one upvote for this (excl mine). Must be not many people out there using Passport-Local-Mongoose :)